How I can handle TS types error MQTT.js with RxJs
I have a problem in attempt to use rxjs with mqtt.js
import { connect, IClientOptions, IPublishPacket, Packet } from "mqtt";
import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { bufferTime, filter, map, takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";

const powerLinesMQTTClient = connect(MQTT_BROKER_URL!, options);

const connect$ = fromEvent(powerLinesMQTTClient, "connect");
const disconnect$ = fromEvent(powerLinesMQTTClient, "disconnect");
const error$ = fromEvent(powerLinesMQTTClient, "error");
const message$ = fromEvent(powerLinesMQTTClient, "message");

connect$.subscribe(onConnect);
disconnect$.subscribe(onDisconnect);
error$.subscribe(onError);
message$
  .pipe(
    filter(([topic]: [string, Buffer, IPublishPacket]) => {
      Logger.log("debug", `[MQTT] PowerLinesMQTTClient subscribed to ${topic}`);
      const { fieldName } = messagesUtils.parseTopic(topic);

      if (Object.values(SupportedTopics).includes(fieldName as SupportedTopics)) {
        return true;
      }
      Logger.log(
        "warn",
        `[MQTT] Warning: this type of messages: ${fieldName} is not handling by PowerLinesMQTTClient`
      );
      return false;
    })
  )
  .pipe(
    map(([topic, payload]): MessageTS => {
      const { fieldName, hostName } = messagesUtils.parseTopic(topic);

and I can`t find out how I can fix it

It seams its a mqtt.js types problem ...
any ideas how I can handle this?
ts-config
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "esNext",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,

    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      /* Support absolute /imports/* with a leading '/' */
      "/*": ["*"],
      /* Pull in type declarations for Meteor packages from either zodern:types or @types/meteor packages */
      "meteor/*": ["node_modules/@types/meteor/*", ".meteor/local/types/packages.d.ts"],
      "meteor/mdg:validated-method": [
        "@types/meteor/mdg:validated-method",
        ".meteor/local/types/packages.d.ts"
      ],
      "meteor/hwillson:stub-collections": [
        "@types/meteor/hwillson:stub-collections",
        ".meteor/local/types/packages.d.ts"
      ],
      "meteor/johanbrook:publication-collector": [
        "@types/meteor/johanbrook:publication-collector",
        ".meteor/local/types/packages.d.ts"
      ],
      "meteor/tunguska:reactive-aggregate": [
        "@types/meteor/tunguska:reactive-aggregate",
        ".meteor/local/types/packages.d.ts"
      ],
      "meteor/percolate:migrations": [
        "@types/meteor/percolate:migrations",
        ".meteor/local/types/packages.d.ts"
      ],
      "meteor/cultofcoders:redis-oplog": [
        "@types/meteor/cultofcoders:redis-oplog",
        ".meteor/local/types/packages.d.ts"
      ],
      "*.ts": ["*"]
    },
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": ["node", "mocha", "@emotion/react/types/css-prop", "meteor", "@types/meteor-roles"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": ["./node_modules/**", "./.meteor/**", "./packages/**"]
}

